# Excel VBA performance issues comparing row to column delete

Tags: vba, performance, excel

Just wondering why column delete took 3 seconds more time to execute like row delete?

> matrixWs

is symmetrical sheet. How to improve code?

```
 If activeRow >= 8 And activeRow < lastRow And deleteRowButton Then

            Debug.Print Now & " start delete normal rows" -->  23:13:53 
            normalWs.Rows(activeRow).EntireRow.Delete

            Debug.Print Now & " lap time before matrix" --> 23:13:53 
            matrixWs.Rows(activeRow).EntireRow.Delete

            Debug.Print Now & " lap time after matrix row" --> 23:13:53 
            matrixWs.Columns(activeRow - 5).EntireColumn.Delete

            Debug.Print Now & " lap time after matrix column" --> 23:13:56

 End If
```

Comment: You want to remove columns but are using a row variable, is that correct? (To me that sounds a little confusing, no?)  Also as you switch the `normalWS` to `matrixWS`, is the `activeRow` what you expect? ...Also maybe turn off calculation and screen updating, depending on how much data/formulas you have in the sheets.

Comment: a row contains 16384 cells and a column contains 1048576 cells

Comment: Charles Williams. That has to be the reason. Column delete is 64 folds bigger job to PC.

Comment: Read this Question for another info:[Improving a Loop to delete rows in excel faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46077673/improving-a-loop-to-delete-rows-in-excel-faster#comment79116863_46077673). Which states that *The fastest way would be to select all the rows first then delete them at once using `Range.Delete`. It's the delete operation that takes the most time. – John Wu Sep 6 at 14:22*