# How to delete complete rows automatically under one condition on vba?

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I'm a beginner with VBA. I have the following simple loop code in order to delete from a data base the rows which have a "na" value on the column 9 cell:

```
Dim n As Integer
n = 500

  For i = 1 To n
  If Cells(i, 9).Value = "n.a." Then
    Rows("i:i").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

   End If
  Next i

End Sub
```

But I get the 1004 error, could anyone help me please?

Comment: It is better to avoid [Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba), and refer to this question to look on the [performance of deleting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46163851/excel-vba-performance-issues-comparing-row-to-column-delete) and [Improving a Loop to delete rows in excel faster](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46077673/7690982). Or [Performance - 1 million rows - Delete rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30959315/7690982). Because if the Worksheet is too large it can become slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim n As Integer
    n = 500

    For i = n To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, 9).value = "n.a." Then
            rows(i & ":" & i).Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Whenever you are deleting rows, start doing it from the biggest to the smallest. Later you can google how to avoid `Select` and how to use `Union` in order to do the deletion in one step. Finally, you can replace `Integer` to `Long`.

Comment: I still get the same error althought I have implemented your modifications, the error text is: "error defined by the application or the object", do you know why is it coming up? Thanks for your help

Comment: @Mauro - try again, `rows(i & ":" & i).Select` was wrong as well

Comment: I still get the same error, I don't understand why because the code seems to be correct.

Comment: Now I get another error: "an object is needed", could it be because I have to actívate first the sheet where I'm working?

Comment: @Mauro - yes if you are using select you have to take care of the activated sheets as well.

Comment: Thank you very much I validate your answer as you were first.

Comment: Cool, thanks @Mauro. Once you have time, investigate the 3 ideas in the answer and try to implement the in your code.

Answer (score 3):

You simply need this...

```
Dim n As Integer
n = 500
  For i = n To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 9).Value = "n.a." Then Rows(i).Delete
  Next i
```

**Edit:**

Or more correctly this to make it dynamic...

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim n As Long
n = Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row
  For i = n To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 9).Value = "n.a." Then Rows(i).Delete
  Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: [The fastest way would be to select all the rows first then delete them at once using Range.Delete. It's the delete operation that takes the most time. – John Wu Sep 6 at 14:22](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46077868/7690982) So it is better to not delet each row and create a non contiguous range or filter for the value to make it faster. Your code works and received thumbs up, just a comment to improve for other people looking in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to delete these values is using AutoFilters. No need for loops.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AutoFilterDelete()

  With Range("I1:I500")
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="n.a"
    .Resize(WorksheetFunction.Match("*", .Cells, -1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
  End With

End Sub
```