# Removing Rows - Code Too Slow

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following which I am using to remove all rows of data where the name in column DX is not a specified name. The code will sort through all rows and delete each row that doesn't contain that specific name. The problem is, it is way too slow.
Any thoughts?

```
 Sub DeleteNonName()


 Dim Firstrow As Long
 Dim Lastrow As Long
 Dim Lrow As Long
 Dim CalcMode As Long
 Dim ViewMode As Long

 With Application
     CalcMode = .Calculation
     .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
     .ScreenUpdating = False
 End With

 With ActiveSheet
     .Select
     ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
     ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
     .DisplayPageBreaks = False
    Firstrow = 2
     Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

     For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
         With .Cells(Lrow, "DX")
             If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                 If InStr(.Value, "Name") = 0 Then .EntireRow.Delete
             End If
         End With
      Next Lrow
     End With

 ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
 With Application
     .ScreenUpdating = True
     .Calculation = CalcMode
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30959315/7690982), the part of the code that takes most time is the deleting task.  So also read [Excel VBA performance issues comparing row to column delete](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46163851/7690982) and [Improving a Loop to delete rows in excel faster](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46077673/7690982). So you should make the delete task just once on your code, it is the fastest way.

Comment: This question is better suited for CodeReview.  That is where you will get help with code that works that needs to be optimized.

Comment: @ScottCraner Aye, except it's always the same answer - quit using `Select`, don't iterate `Range`, use arrays instead; work out which rows you want to delete, merge them into a signle `Range`, and delete that merged range in one single operation. Total worksheet reads: 1. Total worksheet writes: 1.

Comment: @Mat'sMug that may be and is inevitably correct, but that still does not make this a proper question for this site. As is, it is too broad.

Comment: @Mat'sMug, you sayed : "merge them into a signle Range". Can we merge rows even if they are in separated rows? like, merge row 1 and row 4?

Comment: @D.O. he is not talking about cell merge, but using `Union()` to create one range object that gets deleted at once.

Comment: @D.O. You know how you can hold down `Ctrl` and select multiple disjointed rows/cells in Excel? In VBA land, `Union` does that.

Comment: @Scott Craner, @ Mat's Mug, hhhh, yes!!!! Thanks

Comment: are you able to sort the worksheet on the DX column? if yes, how long does it take to execute the sort?

Comment: I have actually solved my problem with a separate code. Should I delete this post or post my solution?

Comment: @NeilD137 Post you solution, so you can help other people with the same problem.

Comment: `> Sub DeleteNotNAME()
> With Range("X2", Cells(Rows.Count, "X").End(xlUp))
>   If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then .AutoFilter`

 >     .AutoFilter Field:=128, Criteria1:="<>NAME"
 >    On Error Resume Next
 >     .SpecialCells(xlVisible).EntireRow.Delete
 >     On Error GoTo 0
 >    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then .AutoFilter
 >     End With 
 >   End Sub`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sub DeleteName()
With ActiveSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    With Range("DX1", Range("DX" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        .AutoFilter 1, "*Name*"
        On Error Resume Next
        .Offset(1).SpecialCells(12).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
    Selection.AutoFilter
End Sub